# systemd-networkd: Set DNS via CLI for managed link

Tags: domain-name-system, command-line-interface, systemd-networkd

I want to set the DNS for an interface managed by systemd-networkd via cli.
The file system is mounted read-only, so is there way to achieve this without manipulating any files?

I tried e.g.:

```
systemd-resolve --interface eth0--set-dns 12.34.56.1 --set-domain lxd
```

This gives me the error:

```
The specified interface eth0 is managed by systemd-networkd. Operation refused.
Please configure DNS settings for systemd-networkd managed interfaces directly in their .network files.`
```

What I also tried is:

```
busctl call org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager SetLinkDNS 'ia(iay)' 2 1 2 4 8 8 8 8
```

Which results in the error: `Link eth0 is managed`

I would like to manipulate the DNS servers during runtime. It is no problem, when they get lost on reboot.